# How can I find the piece of code to which JS i attached?

Tags: javascript

I have an ui-tooltip on the page, it fires on mouseover event of some element. However, I cannot find where it is attached to this element. When I set breakpoint on Mouseover event, Chrome Dev Tools only shows in call stack jquery and jquery-ui functions... And no information about where it is really attached to an element. What is the best way to solve my problem? It's not the first time I am stuck in such way.

Comment: set a breakpoint at the first line of all js files on the page, and step through them. Odds are the event is bound in a file that contains jQ code, because the call stack shows jQ. Normally, it should be quite easy to find _where_ the listeners are bound, though if your knowledge of JS/jQ is decent. Besides: debugging is part of coding, so get used to it ;)

Comment: Thanks, I know, and I'm trying to get used, BTW, I solved my problem, it was as simple as $(document).tooltip(); =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event It should work on event's set during page load or document ready.

Comment: thanks, I think it's not simple solution, but I'll try

Comment: It was useful to me couple of times.